# WordPress Post 403 Error Based on Slug

Tags: posts, errors

For some unknown reason, some of my posts keep producing 403 errors. The only thing I've tried that  actually works is changing the slug / post URL.

Here's the error log in Apache:

> AH01276: Cannot serve directory
> /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/adam-baldwin/: No matching
> DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated
> directory index forbidden by Options directive

In the above example, I changed the post slug from adam-baldwin to adam-baldwin-bio and then the page magically started working.

This only seems to be affecting pages that have short slugs, but it's totally random. Most of the posts work (even short slugs).

Longer slugs don't seem to be affected at all.

Has anyone else ever experienced this???

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out. I'm an idiot. I have image folders on my server that were an exact match as the post's slug.

In the above case, I have a image folder named adam-baldwin which causes a conflict in Apache. Once I changed the slug, the conflict resolved itself.